# How to unlist objects in data.table that is made of data.table and lists made of data.table in R (example given)?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, data.table

i am trying to unlist values from a data.table and make it a data.table as explained below

```
given_y<-data.table(country=c("abc","xyz"),V2=(list(data.table(city=c("Del","Mum","Kol"),age=c(20,30,45)),data.table(city=c("Del","Mum"),age=c(30,45)))))

str(given_y)


Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
$ country: chr  "abc" "xyz"
$ V2     :List of 2
..$ :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
.. ..$ city: chr  "Del" "Mum" "Kol"
.. ..$ age : num  20 30 45
.. ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
..$ :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
.. ..$ city: chr  "Del" "Mum"
.. ..$ age : num  30 45
.. ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

### This is how I want my data

```
expected_y<-data.table(customer=c("abc","abc","abc","xyz","xyz"),city=c("Del","Mum","Kol","Del","Mum"),age=c(20,30,45,30,45))

expected_y

 customer city age
1:      abc  Del  20
2:      abc  Mum  30
3:      abc  Kol  45
4:      xyz  Del  30
5:      xyz  Mum  45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that answers your question using `data.table`

```
given_y[, unlist(.SD[[1]], recursive = F), by = country]

#     country city age
# 1:     abc  Del  20
# 2:     abc  Mum  30
# 3:     abc  Kol  45
# 4:     xyz  Del  30
# 5:     xyz  Mum  45
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I think using `tidyr::unnest` is currently the best option:

```r
as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(given_y, v2))
#    country city age
# 1:     abc  Del  20
# 2:     abc  Mum  30
# 3:     abc  Kol  45
# 4:     xyz  Del  30
# 5:     xyz  Mum  45
```

I've found with some datasets that I needed to add `keep_empty = TRUE`, but that's not required here. (E.g., one of the embedded frames has 0 rows.)

This might lose some internal efficiency since (I believe) it is making a copy of the data (something `data.table` tries really hard to avoid when possible ... not sure it's avoidable here).

There are many discussions of this in rdatatable issues:

- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2159 (closed)
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3672
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4156

Comment: Since my data.table is huge , and when I use the suggested approach 
 then I get this error " cannot allocated vector size"         .Any workaround to bypass this error ?                                                                              
           as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(results4, hr_visitors))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.9 Mb

Comment: Not at the moment, sorry, it's hard to ask and answer about memory problems like that since a reproducible data sample is so difficult. I'll keep chewing over it ...